# Syntactical error when yacc file is called

Tags: perl, nlp, yacc, penn-treebank

I am trying to build an [XTAG](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Extag/) parser from source. The relevant files can be fetched from ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/xtag/lem. I understand that this particular TAG parser is decades old and there are plenty of newer options, but I need this specific parser to work, as I need to use the XTAG grammar, and I do not know of any other parsers that can handle it.

There is a file (treefile.y, among others) that has the following line at the top:
`# -*- perl -*-`. It is being called from a Makefile like: `/usr/bin/byacc -P treefile.py`. I recognize the Emacs mode string, but both `yacc` and `byacc` (version 2.0) throw a syntax error at the "#". I figured it might be a typo, but all yacc files have the same thing. I tried using a shebang like: `#! -*- perl -*-` but to no avail. The README requires Perl version 5 or later, which I have. I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on VirtualBox (it is mentioned that the parser was only ever tested on SunOS 5.7 and Linux 2.2). Any help is appreciated (and if anyone has a suggestion for an alternative to resurrecting an ancient LTAG parser from antiquity, I'd love to know).

Comment: Some quick skimming of the byacc web site suggests you might need something called `perl-byacc`

Comment: (Looks like it's available as an Ubuntu package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer is that resurrecting this ancient software is a lost cause.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).